# How to get Wifi Working Properly - I am Noob

Tags: wireless, networking, usb

I'm a noob to Ubuntu, but not computers.  I installed a full version of Ubuntu version 12 whatever it is.  I run it on a machine that has Win7/Win8 on another hard drive.  My wireless adapter is some tiny USB stick I got on eBay - it works great in Windows, but I can't get it to work in Ubuntu.  More precisely, Ubuntu is providing me a list (sometimes) of wireless networks in the area and when I try to connect to mine it just keeps password prompting me even though the one I use is correct.

I looked over all the settings multiple times and don't believe there is anything in error regarding what it takes to connect to my network.  So, I thought maybe it is a driver issue and came across NDIS.  I thought I should try installing it, but I don't know how when I can't connect the Ubuntu machine to the Internet.  I tried some commands to no avail.  I have the Ubuntu installation disc and it shows a NDIS common and utils .deb files in there.

Can someone out there help me out to get this wireless setup so I can get online?

**June 3:**

I have tried using NDISWRAPPER, but it failed me (the command sudo modprobe ndiswrapper fails).  Then I discovered that there is a Linux driver for my device.  After getting nowhere with ndiswrapper, I decided to uninstall it and I installed the Linux driver.  Somewhere during this process, the wireless card worked and successfully connected to my network, but I couldn't browse the Internet.  No webpages would load.  After restarting the machine, now no networks are displayed.  I still cannot get this thing to work right in Linux.

**June 4:**

I am still trying to get it to work.  I'm using Realtek 8188CU USB wireless adapter.  The commands iwconfig and ifconfig no longer are listing wlan0.

**June 5**

I'm getting a "no device" message.  I tried so many different commands, read so many articles.  Still nothing works.

Comment: I'm assuming you tried the obvious stuff like rebooting, trying a different USB port, disabling/enabling wireless, ect? So let's make sure that Ubuntu is recognizing your interface. Open a terminal (ctrl + alt + T) and type `sudo ifconfig` , you should see a list of available interfaces (eth0, wlan0, ect) and some other information. Post the output, and also the output of `sudo iwconfig`so we can see if there's a problem.

Comment: username@xxx:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:96 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:96 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7840 (7.8 KB)  TX bytes:7840 (7.8 KB)

Comment: wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:02:2a:54:79:6d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::4a02:2aff:fe54:796d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:270 (270.0 B)  TX bytes:306 (306.0 B)

Comment: username@xxx:~$ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

Comment: lo        no wireless extensions.

Comment: Could you please post the version of Ubuntu, the type of USB wireless adapter (brand/model). Show a list of commands used to troubleshoot and outputs ([PasteUbuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) is a good one to use for outputs) And if possible show a list of settings appropriate for device. You could try from a terminal `lsusb` to start.

Comment: Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter

Comment: You can post your outputs in your answer with an edit

Comment: It's great that you found your solution. Please move the solution from the question to the answer. Answering your own question is encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

- Download the Linux drivers for 8188CUS from Realtek.com.tw
- Unpack the file by right clicking on the file and select "Extract Here"
- You should see in that folder "install.sh"
- Open a terminal window, navigate to your folder (cd /blahhh/more blahh/foldername), then type "sudo bash install.sh"
- It might have an error, but still seems to work
- In the terminal window type "sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"
- Go to the bottom of the file, hit enter a few times to give you some space
- type "# blacklisting Realtek 8188CU native drivers" and press enter
- type "blacklist rtl8192cu" and press enter
- type "blacklist rtl8192c_common" and press enter
- type "blacklist rtlwifi" and press enter
- restart the machine

DONE!!!